# How to get db connection from HikariCP

Tags: java, playframework, ebean, hikaricp

I added HikariCP and Ebean to my Play Framework project.

When the project starts, Play reporting that connection pool is created:

```
[info] application - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
```

How can I retrieve this pool/connections for my own modules?

Versions: Play 2.5 (java), built-in HikariCP, built-in ebean

Comment: And can I have two pools for one db?

Comment: Use injection. Just declare a parameter of type Database and then call getConnection() on it. Also, if you want to research this more independently, google for "Obtaining a JDBC connection" You should find this page: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaDatabase